# Long time to load the edit page for any node?

Tags: nodes

I have a rare issue in a site. Every works fine but if I hit the edit link for any node it takes a very long time (about 1 minute), then the page is loaded correctly.

This only happens when editing a node.

How can I spot the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module, enable it, go to: `admin/config/development/devel`, check "Display query log", "Display page timer" and "Display memory usage" and analyze the results displayed at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I get no results at all at the bottom of the page. I just see the report in the admin pages, but not in the frontend of the site. Do I need to have any other module?

Comment: My mistake, I was checking on a view page. The report is shown correctly in all nodes.